# Parametrized stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have written a stored procedure which needs parameters `@day` and `@customer` when being executed:

```
Exec StoredProcedure_name @day, @customer name  

Exec StoredProcedure_name 5, 'vale'
```

This stored procedure will always take day and customer name as parameter; if day is passed as blank like

```
Exec StoredProcedure_name '', 'vale'
```

then it will take 6 days as default as per logic.

Is there any way to write a stored procedure in such a way it will take my day parameter should be optional. If user want to provide day then he will right command like this

```
Exec StoredProcedure_name 7, 'vale'
```

(means he wants 7 days data) other wise he just simply enter Customer name parameter like

```
Exec StoredProcedure_name @customer
```

and stored procedure will use a default of 6 days of data rather then calling command like

```
Exec StoredProcedure_name '', 'vale'.
```

Comment: Optional parameter: `@day INT = NULL` How to not have to call it: Name your parameters (e.g. `EXEC dbo.procedure_name @customer = 'vale';`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in your stored procedure definition

```
Create Procedure ProcedureName @vale varchar(50), @day int=6
AS
```

Comment: And when the call is made like this: `Exec StoredProcedure_name 7, 'vale'` - what happens then??

Comment: it will take 7 as day, as 6 is made default value which will be set when day is not passed.